# PowerBI DAX for vendor count with annual spend

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I need your super strength in the following problem:

I have purchase doc with order values.
I want distinct list of all the vendors where net annual spend for that vendor is less than $1000.
for example, the final will be something like that:

```
 Amazon -- $500  --  2017 (Ebay will be omitted as net order per annum is more than $1000)
 Ebay   -- $75   --  2018
 Amazon -- $1000 -- 2018
```

[image: Sample data set for the question]

Comment: Adding image is not a good practice. Can you convert your data from image to tabular format?

Answer (score 1):

Do this following steps to achieve your required output-

Considering your table name: **vendor_details**

**Step-1:** Create this following Measure in your table-

```
total_order_value = SUM(vendor_details[order value])
```

**Step-2:** Add these following column/measure to your table visual-

```
Vendor
Year
total_order_value
```

**Step-3:** Add filter to your table visual as below-

[image]

This all done now. You should have a output as below-

[image]

> Your expected 3rd row is not here as total value in 1300 for Amazon in year 2018.